# What happened to Masaki's family?

Tags: bleach

In Bleach, Ichigo's mother Masaki

> was a quincy and was living with Uryuu's father, Ryuken Ishida as a teenager.

She was the last of the Kurosaki line. What happened to her family? How did they die?

Comment: At this time it is unknown what happened to her family.

Comment: Correction: Masaki was not the last of the Kurosaki line. Masaki married into the Kurosaki family, hence Ichigp's last name being Kurosaki as well.

Answer (score 1):

It hasn't been told in manga yet. We can only speculate.

The Great Quincy War can't be the reason as it happened 200 years ago. We can safely presume they died of natural causes and also they were Echt Quincies (pure-blooded Quincies who refuse to marry and mate with anyone but a pure-blooded Quincy and who were almost extinct after the Great Purge).